# Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: react-native

I have create new react-native app when i run this app using npx
 react-native run-android this error is showing

```
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not set up android environment in you computer. If you have not already please follow this link and choose React Native CLI Quickstart
[React native quickstart with development configuration for each platform](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)